# Use the markovchain package to compare two empirically estimated Markov chains

Tags: r, markov-chains, markov

I need to compare two probability matrices to know the degree of proximity of the chains, so I would use the resulting P-Value of the test.

I tried to use the markovchain r package, more specifically the divergenceTest function. But, the problem is that the function is not properly implemented. It is based on the test of the book "[Statistical Inference Based on Divergence Measures](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=ziDGGIkhqlMC&pg=PA139&dq=%22markov%20chains%22%20divergence&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oEJ5T8efMKqUiQKN1b2nDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22markov%20chains%22%20divergence&f=false)" on page 139, I contacted the package developers, but they still have not corrected, so I tried to implement, but I'm having trouble, could anyone help me to find the error?

Parameters: freq_matrix: Is a frequency matrix used to estimate the probability matrix. hypothetic: Is the matrix used to compare with the estimated matrix.

```
divergenceTest3 <- function(freq_matrix, hypothetic){  
  n <- sum(freq_matrix)
  empirical = freq_matrix
  for (i in 1:length(hypothetic)){
    empirical[i,] <- freq_matrix[i,]/rowSums(freq_matrix)[i]
  }
  M <- nrow(empirical)
  v <- numeric()
  out <- 2 * n / .phi2(1)
  sum <- 0
  c <- 0  
  for(i in 1:M){    
    sum2 <- 0
    sum3 <- 0    
    for(j in 1:M){
      if(hypothetic[i, j] > 0){
        c <- c + 1
      }      
      sum2 <- sum2 + hypothetic[i, j] * .phi(empirical[i, j] / hypothetic[i, j])
    }    
    v[i] <- rowSums(freq_matrix)[i]
    sum <- sum + ((v[i] / n) * sum2)
  }
  TStat <- out * sum
  pvalue <- 1 - pchisq(TStat, c-M)  
  cat("The Divergence test statistic is: ", TStat, " the Chi-Square d.f. are: ", c-M," the p-value is: ", pvalue,"\n")
  out <- list(statistic = TStat, p.value = pvalue)  
  return(out)
}
# phi function for divergence test
.phi <- function(x) {
  out <- x*log(x) - x + 1
  return(out)
}
# another phi function for divergence test
.phi2 <- function(x) {
  out <- 1/x
  return(out)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The divergence test has been replaced by the `verifyHomogeneity`function. It requires and input list of elements that can be coerced to a raw transition matrix (as of createSequenceMatrix). Then it tests whether they belong to the same unknown DTMC.

See the example below:

```
myMatr1<-matrix(c(0.2,.8,.5,.5),byrow=TRUE, nrow=2)
myMatr2<-matrix(c(0.5,.5,.4,.6),byrow=TRUE, nrow=2)
mc1<-as(myMatr1,"markovchain")
mc2<-as(myMatr2,"markovchain")
mc
mc2
sample1<-rmarkovchain(n=100, object=mc1)
sample2<-rmarkovchain(n=200, object=mc2)
# should reject
verifyHomogeneity(inputList = list(sample1,sample2))
#should accept
sample2<-rmarkovchain(n=200, object=mc1)
verifyHomogeneity(inputList = list(sample1,sample2))
```

Comment: Hello professor, this function seems to work fine now! But, in the documentation only says that the test of article [S. Kullback at all, Tests for Contingency Tables and Markov Chains], correct? I would like to know specifically which equation you have implemented, since I need to understand the test and I am having difficulties.

Thanks in advance!